# How to res.send something in loopback-next

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a function that has a callback as shown below, and I want to return account that is returned in the callback as a response to the request for the function. How could I res.send the account (since I cannot return values from a callback function)

```
@get('/payments/retrieve-stripe/{id}', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'User model instance',
        content: {'application/json': {schema: {'x-ts-type': User}}},
      },
    },
  })
  async retrieveStripe(@param.path.number('id') id: number,
  @requestBody() req: any): Promise<any> {
    if (!req.stripeAccountId) {
      throw new HttpErrors.NotFound('No Stripe Account');
    }
    else {
    stripe.accounts.retrieve(
  req.stripeAccountId,
  async function(err: any, account: any) {
    //console.log(err)
   console.log(account)
    return account
  })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're stuck using a callback any any point in your code you're going to use manual promises (or maybe some promise wrapping library).

Instead of using `async` and `return`, use `resolve()` which functionally can `return` from any point in your function, regardless of scope.

```
@get('/payments/retrieve-stripe/{id}', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'User model instance',
        content: {'application/json': {schema: {'x-ts-type': User}}},
      },
    },
  })
  retrieveStripe(@param.path.number('id') id: number, @requestBody() req: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!req.stripeAccountId) {
        throw new HttpErrors.NotFound('No Stripe Account');
      }
      else {
        stripe.accounts.retrieve(req.stripeAccountId, function(err: any, account: any) {
          resolve(account);
        })
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: In one case, I need to use async await to get some data from the database. Is it fine to have both in one function?

Comment: Probably, I'd have to see your use case though.

Comment: async retrieveStripe(@param.path.number('id') id: number, @requestBody() req: any): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.userRepository.findById(id)
    const stripeAccountId = user.stripeAccountId
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      else {
        stripe.accounts.retrieve(stripeAccountId, function(err: any, account: any) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err)
          }
          else {
            resolve(account);
          }
        })
      }
    });
  }
I removed portions to fit in comments

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, try asking another question